# Get undefined when iterate through objects in array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## What I want to do

**Iterating through `allCategory` and mapping each category.**
#Code

```
class Add_Give_Item_Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //   #インプット情報用
      info: {
        name: '',
        owner: '',
        keyword1: '',
        keyword2: '',
        keyword3: '',
        bland: '',
        state: '未使用、新品',
        category:"" ,
        image: '',
        detail: '',
        url: '',
      },
      //   Validation用
      // 　urlは必須項目ではないのでValidationには含めない
      message: {
        name: '',
        keyword1: '',
        keyword2: '',
        keyword3: '',
        bland: '',
        state: '',
        category: '',
        image: '',
        detail: '',
        url: '',
      },
      allCategory: [],
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:8000/api/category')
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, allCategory: [res.data] });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

render() {
    const { info, message, allCategory } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>

        <label>Category</label>
        <ul>
            {this.state.allCategory.map((category) => { 
                return (
                <li>{category.name}</li>
            )})}
        </ul>
```

I just want to map each category by iterating through objects in an array.
When I write the below code, I got these objects.

```
{this.state.allCategory.forEach((category) => { console.log(category) })}
```

```
(11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, parent: null, name: "Men"}
1: {id: 2, parent: null, name: "Women"}
2: {id: 3, parent: "Women", name: "香水"}
3: {id: 4, parent: "Men", name: "ガジェット"}
4: {id: 5, parent: "Men", name: "スポーツ"}
5: {id: 6, parent: "Women", name: "バッグ"}
6: {id: 7, parent: "Women", name: "靴"}
7: {id: 8, parent: "靴", name: "スニーカー"}
8: {id: 9, parent: "スポーツ", name: "ユニフォーム"}
9: {id: 10, parent: "ガジェット", name: "スマートフォン"}
10: {id: 11, parent: "ガジェット", name: "タブレット"}
length: 11
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I mean, I definitely get these objects so I think this should work in order to get each name of category.

```
{this.state.allCategory.forEach((category) => { console.log(category.name) })}
```

However, I got `undefined`.

I don't know why I wasn't able to map each name of category although I got each object.

I would like you to teach me how to figure out this problem.
And, if it is alright with you, I would love you to teach me why my attempts didn't work.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `map` not `forEach`.

Comment: `allCategory: [res.data]`: if the data from the server is an array, this will actually give you nested arrays: `allCategory: [[ /* the data */ ]]`

Comment: That console is from your forEach on category? It seens like it is a array, doing `category.name` wont work

Comment: @shamsup `res.data` is just chunk of objects. I did `console.log(res.data)`. I got `res.data is [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`. So if I don't put brackets, I have to do `[this.state.allCategory].filter` in order to use `filter`.

Comment: @WilliamRizzi Yes. That console is from `category`, or `allCategory`. Would you like tell me why `category.name` won't work? After I do `forEach` or `map`, category` is going to be an object that contains each category. That's why I thought I could use `category.name`.

Comment: a "chunk of objects" isn't a type. An array is how a collection of objects would be represented. If your console output from `allCategory.forEach((category) => { console.log(category) })}` is the array of categories, then allCategory is an array with a single array that contains the data.

Comment: @Toshi023Yuki what i'm trying to say is exactly what shamsup said. It looks like `allCategory` is a array that contains a array. Try to acess `category[0].name`.

`this.state.allCategory.forEach((category) => { console.log(category[0].name) })`

Comment: @Toshi023Yuki what is the exact output if you add  `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.allCategory)` in your render function?

Answer (score 0):

If `{this.state.allCategory.forEach((category) => { console.log(category) })}` outputs an array of categories in the console instead of each category object individually, then the `res.data` is already an array.

In this callback, you are placing data into an array

```js
.then((res) => {
  this.setState({ ...this.state, allCategory: [res.data] });
})
```

which is giving an object that looks like this:

```js
allCategory: [
  [
    {id: 1, parent: null, name: "Men"},
    {id: 2, parent: null, name: "Women"},
    // ...
  ]
]
```

This is a nested array, so the array of objects expected is actually at `allCategory[0]`.

In order to map through the data like you are expecting, you should change the state value to this instead, so it isn't nested inside of an extra array:

```js
this.setState({ ...this.state, allCategory: res.data });
```

This will give you each category as a single item in the array as you expect:

```js
this.state.allCategory.forEach((category) => { console.log(category.name) })
// > "Men"
// > "Women"
// ... etc
```

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work. Since `res.data` is not an array, I cannot use `filter` or `array` to `this.state.allCategory`. I mean, I experienced this so I put brackets to `res.data`. But thank you for giving me good advise.

Answer (score 0):

I finally why this error happened.
I didn't quite assign `res.data` to `this.state.allCategory` because `setState` does an asynchronous task.

Thank you very much for giving me a lot of adivices.